Public wifi connecting without prompt on a new OS
I installed Ubuntu on my personal laptop and connected to a hotel wifi which I had previously used with Windows on the same PC. This network is a standard hotel wifi where you need to put your credentials as a guest in order to obtain access, but it connected directly with no prompt whatsoever like it bypassed the router prompt.
My question is how? Did it detect my laptop's MAC address and then just assume it was me?

It's likely that the hotel's network recognized your laptop's MAC address. When you first connected to the hotel Wi-Fi on Windows, your laptop's Wi-Fi adapter MAC address was registered with the hotel's network after you authenticated. MAC addresses are hardware specific and remain the same regardless of the operating system you're using.
Most captive portal systems (the login pages hotels use) store authenticated MAC addresses for a certain period after which this automatic recognition will expire, and you'll need to authenticate again to log in.

Great answer! The only thing I would add is that the MAC addresses are specific to the WiFi and Ethernet chip in each laptop. If one uses Ethernet cable to contact to the same hotel network, it will have a different MAC address and one may have to authenticate again.

That's what i suspected. Thank you very much, your answer was on point.
